# mvn tomcat7:run - How to add properties

Tags: maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

How can I add jvm properties?

for example I wish to add the following

"
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the JVM properties on the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable, i.e. on Linux

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

or on Windows create a new environment variable with name MAVEN_OPTS and the JVM properties as value.

If you run maven from the command line on windows you can also set the MAVEN_OPTS temporarily using the command

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

Comment: erm... that will affect all the maven run? i only want it for certain applications

Comment: Yes, it would affect all of them. But unless you are running multiple apps via Maven in parallel it shouldn't cause any harm.